# Display Google Analytics data for downloads on a Drupal site

Tags: drupal, google-analytics

I have a Drupal website where people can download books. I want to be able to display Google analytics statistics showing how many people have downloaded a book on the book page. I thought I could have a block displaying on each book page to show the number of downloads. Each book can be downloaded in three different formats, so there would be a figure for each format. Does anyone know how I can do this?

I did have a look at the Google Analytics Counter module but this looks like it displays page views and not file downloads.

Answer (score 0):

We have done this for other static sites. Have you had a look at this article from Google
http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55529

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen that article. Drupal can automatically track downloads, so this part is not my difficulty. My difficulty is displaying the download data.